# Procedure or function 'sp256' expects parameter '@countcase', which was not supplied

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, optional-parameters, output-parameter

Using SQL Server 2008.

Wanted to output a parameter (`@countcase`) from a stored procedure called `sp256`. But when I exec the stored procedure, an error shows up:

> Procedure or function 'sp256' expects parameter '@countcase', which was not supplied.

The query was to count the total number cases with contact date later than 1 Nov 2016 and output as a parameter.

The stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC sp256
     @countcase AS INT OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT @countcase = COUNT(DISTINCT case_referenceid)
    FROM Cases
    WHERE case_contactdatetime > '2016-11-01'

    --RETURN
END
```

The `EXEC` statement:

```
  DECLARE @reference INT

  EXEC @reference = sp256

  SELECT @reference AS [List of cases]
```

PS: the @countcase should output 268 cases in total.

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proc structure sets an output parameter, doesn't return a value. So that you need to provide an output parameter as expected.

```
EXEC dbo.sp256 @reference output
```